# spring file upload

Tags: file-upload, spring-mvc, jupload

Is any body know how to upload files using jupload in spring frame work.how to handle the jupload request in spring?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter which client you use to do the file upload, the server-side logic should be the same.

Spring's File Upload handling is documented [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart).